# Endless loop with Bank Simulation

Tags: c++, debugging, nullptr

Hi when I run the bank simulation it gets caught in an endless loop on the last customer unable to remove the event from the list I don't know how to rework the logic to fix this issue. 
MY current function protects removing the first event before its processed but also causes the loop to get caught on the last event

problem code in EventList class method RemoveEvent()

```
Event* EventList::removeEvent()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            cout << "Cannot remove event from empty list" << endl;
        Event* tmp = front;
        if (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
            deleteFront();
            front = tmp;
        }

        return tmp;
    }

#include "Bank.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

Bank::Bank()
{
    totalCustomers = 0;
    totalTime = 0;
    currentTime = 0;
    closingTime = 60 * 60;//(60 * 60 * 8);
    list = new EventList();
    win1 = new Queue();
    win2 = new Queue();
    win3 = new Queue();
    win4 = new Queue();
}

Bank::Bank(Event* event)
{
    totalCustomers = 0;
    totalTime = 0;
    currentTime = event->occurTime;
    closingTime = (60 * 60 * 8);
    list = new EventList();
    list->insertEnd(event);
    win1 = new Queue();
    win2 = new Queue();
    win3 = new Queue();
    win4 = new Queue();
}

Bank::~Bank()
{
    win1->clear();
    win2->clear();
    win3->clear();
    win4->clear();
    list->clearList();
}

int Bank::avgTime()
{
    int avg = totalTime / totalCustomers;
    return avg;
}

int Bank::genService()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int time = rand() % 20 + 1;
    time *= 60;
    return time;
}

int Bank::genArrival(Customer* customer)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int time = rand() % 5 + 1;
    time *= 60;
    time += customer->arrivalTime;
    return time;
}

int Bank::departTime(Customer* tmp)
{
    int depart;
    depart = tmp->arrivalTime + tmp->serviceTime;
    return depart;
}

bool Bank::emptyWindows()
{
    if (win1->isEmpty() || win2->isEmpty() || win3->isEmpty() || win4->isEmpty())
        return true;
    return false;
}

int Bank::checkType(int eventType)
{
    switch (eventType)
    {
        case 1: return 1; break;
        case 2: return 2; break;
        case 3: return 3; break;
        case 4: return 4; break;
        default: return 0; break;
    }
}

void Bank::customerArrival(Event* event)
{
    Customer* customer = new Customer;
    customer->arrivalTime = event->occurTime;
    int time = genService();
    customer->serviceTime = time;
    customer->nextCustomer = NULL;
    int nxtArrival = genArrival(customer);

    if (nxtArrival < closingTime)
    {
        Event* arriveEvent = new Event;
        arriveEvent->occurTime = nxtArrival;
        arriveEvent->type = 0;
        arriveEvent->next = NULL;

        Event* p = list->getFront();
        if (list->isEmpty())
            list->frontInsert(arriveEvent);
        else {
            while (p->occurTime < nxtArrival && p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            if (nxtArrival > p->occurTime)
                list->insertEnd(arriveEvent);
            else
                list->midInsert(arriveEvent, p);
        }
    }

    int num1, num2, num3, num4;
    if (!emptyWindows())
    {
        num1 = win1->getSize();
        num2 = win2->getSize();
        num3 = win3->getSize();
        num4 = win4->getSize();

        if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3 && num1 < num4)
            win1->enQueue(customer);
        else if (num2 < num3 && num2 < num4)
            win2->enQueue(customer);
        else if (num3 < num4)
            win3->enQueue(customer);
        else
            win4->enQueue(customer);
    }
    if (win1->isEmpty())
    {
        Event* depart = new Event;
        depart->occurTime = customer->arrivalTime + customer->serviceTime;
        depart->type = 1;
        depart->next = NULL;
        win1->enQueue(customer);

        Event* p = list->getFront();
        while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
            list->insertEnd(depart);
        else
            list->midInsert(depart, p);
    }
    else if (win2->isEmpty())
    {
        Event* depart = new Event;
        depart->occurTime = customer->arrivalTime + customer->serviceTime;
        depart->type = 2;
        depart->next = NULL;
        win2->enQueue(customer);

        Event* p = list->getFront();
        while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
            list->insertEnd(depart);
        else
            list->midInsert(depart, p);
    }
    else if (win3->isEmpty())
    {
        Event* depart = new Event;
        depart->occurTime = departTime(customer);
        depart->type = 3;
        depart->next = NULL;
        win3->enQueue(customer);

        Event* p = list->getFront();
        while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
            list->insertEnd(depart);
        else
            list->midInsert(depart, p);
    }
    else if (win4->isEmpty())
    {
        Event* depart = new Event;
        depart->occurTime = departTime(customer);
        depart->type = 4;
        depart->next = NULL;
        win4->enQueue(customer);

        Event* p = list->getFront();
        while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
            p = p->next;
        if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
            list->insertEnd(depart);
        else
            list->midInsert(depart, p);
    }
    totalCustomers++;
}

int Bank::customerDepart(Event* event)
{
    int tmpType = checkType(event->type);
    Customer* nxt;
    int stayingTime = 0;

    if (tmpType == 1)
    {
        Customer* tmp = win1->getHead();
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            stayingTime += event->occurTime - tmp->arrivalTime;
            win1->dlQueue();
        }

        if (!win1->isEmpty())
        {
            nxt = win1->getHead();
            Event* depart = new Event;
            depart->occurTime = event->occurTime + nxt->serviceTime;
            depart->type = 1;
            depart->next = NULL;

            Event* p = list->getFront();
            while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
                list->insertEnd(depart);
            else
                list->midInsert(depart, p);
        }
    }
    else if (tmpType == 2)
    {
        Customer* tmp = win2->getHead();
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            stayingTime += event->occurTime - tmp->arrivalTime;
            win2->dlQueue();
        }

        if (!win2->isEmpty())
        {
            nxt = win2->getHead();
            Event* depart = new Event;
            depart->occurTime = event->occurTime + nxt->serviceTime;
            depart->type = 2;
            depart->next = NULL;

            Event* p = list->getFront();
            while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
                list->insertEnd(depart);
            else
                list->midInsert(depart, p);
        }
    }
    else if (tmpType == 3)
    {
        Customer* tmp = win3->getHead();
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            stayingTime += event->occurTime - tmp->arrivalTime;
            win3->dlQueue();
        }

        if (!win3->isEmpty())
        {
            nxt = win3->getHead();
            Event* depart = new Event;
            depart->occurTime = event->occurTime + nxt->serviceTime;
            depart->type = 3;
            depart->next = NULL;

            Event* p = list->getFront();
            while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
                list->insertEnd(depart);
            else
                list->midInsert(depart, p);
        }
    }
    else if (tmpType == 4)
    {
        Customer* tmp = win4->getHead();
        if (tmp != NULL)
        {
            stayingTime += event->occurTime - tmp->arrivalTime;
            win4->dlQueue();
        }

        if (!win4->isEmpty())
        {
            nxt = win4->getHead();
            Event* depart = new Event;
            depart->occurTime = event->occurTime + nxt->serviceTime;
            depart->type = 4;
            depart->next = NULL;

            Event* p = list->getFront();
            while (p->occurTime < depart->occurTime && p->next != NULL)
                p = p->next;
            if (depart->occurTime > p->occurTime)
                list->insertEnd(depart);
            else
                list->midInsert(depart, p);
        }
    }
    return stayingTime;
}

void Bank::runSimulation() //caught in endless loop
{
    if (currentTime == 0)
    {
        list->addNode(currentTime, 0);
    }
    Event* currentEvent;
    while (!list->isEmpty())
    {
        currentEvent = list->removeEvent();

        if (currentEvent->type == 0)
        {
            customerArrival(currentEvent);
            currentTime = currentEvent->occurTime;
        }
        else
        {
            customerDepart(currentEvent);
            currentTime = currentEvent->occurTime;
        }
    }
    int avg = avgTime();
    printResults(avg);
}

void Bank::printResults(int avg)
{
    cout << "Total Customers:" << totalCustomers << endl;
    cout << "Total Time:" << totalTime << endl;
    cout << "Avg Staying Time:" << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: How do you know the problem is in `removeEvent()` itself and not somewhere else?

Comment: OT: `srand(time(NULL));` in `Bank::genArrival` you probably should not have this here. It's usually better to seed the random number generator 1 time at beginning of main. If you call genArrival() in a loop you could get the same sequence of random numbers because of reseeding it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant find my error in Logic! Unable to End Bank Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263542/cant-find-my-error-in-logic-unable-to-end-bank-simulation) Note: This question was posted by **the same user**!

Answer (score 1):

figured it out just returned the event at the front of the list then deleted the front after the execution as the last part of the loop before the loop restarts

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is a problem in removeEvent() method. You don't handle properly the situation when the queue has only one element. This causes an infinite loop.

```
Event* EventList::removeEvent()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            cout << "Cannot remove event from empty list" << endl;
        Event* tmp = front;
        if (tmp != NULL) {
            tmp = (tmp->next != NULL) ? tmp->next : null;
            deleteFront();
            front = tmp;
        }

        return tmp;
    }
```

Maybe instead of creating your own queue class you should think about start using std::queue template from standard library.